# How do I protect a function parameter without modification within class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, api-design

Suppose, I have a class called `UserSettings`, and the other class `Work`. 
`UserSettings` has many read-write properties for user's settings. 
`Work` has a designated initializer `initWithSetting:`, like the following code,

```
// Work.m
@interface Work() 
{
    UserSettings * _settings;
}

@end

@implementation Work 
- (instancetype)initWithSettings:(UserSettings *)settings {
    if (self = [super init]) {
          _settings = settings;
    }

    return self;
}   
@end
```

In class `Work`, it won't change any data in the class instance `settings`. My question is how to prevent the following code in class `Work`

```
// I hope it will give compilation error or warning. 
_settings.color = @"red";
```

I have tried to use `const` and make the property as `readonly`, but no luck. For example,

```
// Work.m
@interface Work() 

@property(readonly) UserSettings * settings;

@end

@implementation Work 
- (instancetype)initWithSettings:(UserSettings *)settings {
    if (self = [super init]) {
          _settings = settings;
          self.settings.color = @"red";   // this still work
    }

    return self;
}   
@end
```

Comment: Your code `self.settings.color = @"blah"` is not changing the property `self.settings` it is changing the property `settings.color`. If you don't want those to be changed then you need to be looking at the property settings for `color` inside the `UserSettings` class.

Comment: @Fogmeister, thanks. from my testing here, `self.settings.color=@"blah"` does change it from its original value (e.g. black) to "blah".   I thought about changing the property of `color` to read-only, however, if so, a user will not be able to set its value, and the `color` only can be inited in `UserSettings` class internally.

Comment: Yeah, you are still only changing the colour though. You are not changing the actual settings object itself. Check the memory reference for `self.settings` before and after changing the colour. It doesn’t change. What you want is to stop the properties of the UserSettings to remain the same. It is a different question from the one you have asked and will lead to a different answer.

Comment: Putting it another way. What you are doing by making `settings` into read only is to stop the `settings` object from being replaced by another settings object. When you change the colour of it you are not replacing the settings object at all. You change the `color` from green to black and it is still the same settings object, it just has a different color. If you repaint your car from green to black, is it a different car? No, it is the same car, but has a different color. That is what I'm trying to say. You need to stop the properties of settings from being changed inside the `UserSettings`

Comment: If you want to enable changing the colours elsewhere you could, perhaps, provide a factory style method that allows you to create a new settings object with a provided color. e.g. `newSettings = [oldSettings withColor: @"green"];` then you get back a new instance of `UserSettings`. Which would not be allowed here (with read only) and would be allowed elsewhere (with read write).

Comment: You could try subclassing the UserSettings and overriding the properties with read only versions.  Of course it's a fair bit of work if you have a lot of properties.

Answer (score 0):

Same paradigm like with `NSString` and `NSMutableString`, `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary`.

Implement `UserSettings` only with getters.
Subclass `MutableUserSettings` from `UserSettings`, add setters.

Instance variables declare in header with `@protected` to be able access them in `MutableUserSettings`.

Comment: Thanks. this is what I am thinking as well.